# Lower semicontinuity of a functional $F[u]$ whose integral domain depends on $u$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbf{R}^2$ is a bounded finite domain,e.g. $\Omega=[0,1]^2$, $h,g\in C^\infty(\Omega)$ and $u\in BV(\Omega;[0,1])$ where $BV$ denotes the space of bounded variations. (See the book of *Functions of Bounded Variation and Free Discontinuity Problems - Luigi Ambrosio, Nicola Fusco, Diego Pallara* for more information.)

I want to prove that the following functional is lower semicontinuous in the space of bounded variations.

$F[u] = \sum_{k>0}\int_{\Omega}\mathbf{1}_{\{\beta \cdot k \leq \gamma(u(x,y))\leq \beta(k+1)\}}\left(h(x,y)+u(x,y)\bar{\gamma}_{u,k}\right)^2 dx dy$

where $\beta$ is a constant greater than $0$, $\bar{\gamma}_{u,k}$ is the average of $\gamma(x,y,u)=\int_0^1 (\partial_x g(x+s\cdot u(x,y),y) d s$ in the domain given by $\beta\cdot k \leq \gamma(u)\leq \beta (k+1)$.

Any idea is good. Thank you very much :). And don't hesitate to tell me if the notation is too confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you consider over the space $BV(\Omega,[0,1])$ the norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{BV}=\Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^1}+V(\cdot,\Omega)$. I will also assume either $\Omega$ is compact or $g$ is such that $\partial_{x}g$ is bounded.

---

Let $u_n$ a sequence in $BV(\Omega,[0,1])$, s.t. $u_n\to u$. Consider a subsequence $u_{l_n}$ s.t. 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}F[u_{l_n}]=\liminf_{n\to\infty}F[u_n]
$$

This subsequence converges to $u$ in $L^1$, that is, $\Vert u_{l_n}-u\Vert_{L^1}\to 0$. Then this sequence has a subsequence (which we will denote $u_{l_n}$ for simplicity) s.t. $u_{l_n}\to u$ a.e.

For this subsequence we can show $\gamma(x,y,u_{l_n}(x,y))\to \gamma(x,y,u(x,y))$ a.e., using $\partial_{x}g$ continuous and dominated convergence theorem. This also implies, for all $k$, $\bar{\gamma}_{u_{l_n},k}\to\bar{\gamma}_{u,k}$ and $1_{\{\beta k\leq \gamma(u_{l_n})\leq \beta (k+1)\} }\to 1_{\{\beta k\leq \gamma(u)\leq \beta (k+1)\}}$ a.e.

By Fatou Lemma, we deduce, for all $k$, 
$$
\int 1_{\{\beta k\leq \gamma(u)\leq \beta (k+1)\}}(h(x,y)+\bar{\gamma}_{u,k}u(x,y))^2dxdy \\
=\int\liminf_{n\to\infty}1_{\{\beta k\leq \gamma(u_{l_n})\leq \beta (k+1)\}}(h(x,y)+\bar{\gamma}_{u_{l_n},k}u_{l_n}(x,y))^2dxdy \\
\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\int 1_{\{\beta k\leq \gamma(u_{l_n})\leq \beta (k+1)\}}(h(x,y)+\bar{\gamma}_{u_{l_n},k}u_{l_n}(x,y))^2dxdy
$$

which implies 
\begin{eqnarray}
F[u] & \leq & \liminf_{n\to\infty}F[u_{l_n}])\\
& = &\lim_{n\to\infty} F[u_{l_n}]\\
& = &\liminf_{n\to\infty} F[u_n] 
\end{eqnarray}